# Unmarshell with customize deserializer using Jackson

Tags: jackson, deserialization, marshalling, unmarshalling, jackson-databind

i have a json string like this

```
{"jobs":[{"id":"1","state":"Visited","runTime":6224,"finalJobAssignment":{"owner":"10.107.181.236:5363",
"resourceId":"11",
"listingPositions":["11"]},"keys":1765624,"range":{"startPrefix":"aa",
"endPrefix":"bb"},"resources":[{"resourceId":"11"}]},{"id":"2","state":"Visited","runTime":6224,"finalJobAssignment":{"owner":"10.107.181.236:5363",
"resourceId":"22",
"listingPositions":["22","33"]},"keys":1765624,"range":{"startPrefix":"cc",
"endPrefix":"dd"},"resources":[{"resourceId":"22"}]}]}
```

im trying to deserialize using a custom deserializer, i only need resourceId, startPrefix, endPrefix and listingPositions(which is a list) from the json array, how do i get rid of "jobs" and return a list of my custom object?

custom object only has above useful fields

Currently i have something like this

```java
private List<AuditEntry> deserialize(final JsonNode node,
                                         final DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        List<AuditEntry> res =  new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<JsonNode> iterator = node.get(JOBS_KEY).elements();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode jsonNode = iterator.next();
            final String startKey = jsonNode.get(RANGE_KEY).get(START_PREFIX_KEY).asText();
            final String endKey = jsonNode.get(RANGE_KEY).get(END_PREFIX_KEY).asText();
            final String partitionId;
            final String resourceId;
            final List<JournalChapterAndSN> listingPositions;
            final JsonParser listingPositionsParser;


                resourceId = jsonNode.get(FINAL_JOB_ASSIGNMENT_KEY).get(RESOURCE_ID_KEY).asText();

                listingPositionsParser = jsonNode.get(FINAL_JOB_ASSIGNMENT_KEY).get(LISTING_POSITIONS_KEY).traverse();

                listingPositionsParser.nextToken();

                List<String> listingPositionsString = deserializationContext.readValue(listingPositionsParser, List.class);

                }
            }

            res.add(new AuditEntry(range, partitionId, listingPositions));

        }
        return res;


    }
```

However when processing listingPositionString, DeserializationContext seems to be using my custom deserializer instead of the default one, resulting npe, how can i resolve this?